# How to show Previous and Next link in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Below is my example code that is dynamically get the posts.

```
<?php

    global $post;
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 4 );
    $the_posts = get_posts( $args );

    foreach( $the_posts as $post ){ ?>

    //The Post Content Goes here...

?>
```

The code above will works correctly but my question is, since this is not a default blog page or a category, how can I use the posts_nav_link() so that I can still access the rest of the pages? I tried to used it but it doesn't work unless if the current page is a category. Hope you guys can help me this.

Answer (score 2):

If you giving you paging in your custom post type. then i think you can do very simple you have to use wordpress plugin like **wp-pagenavi** after then add your custom post type in this plugin in admin panel after then add

```
<div class="pagination">
    <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
</div>

<?php

    global $post;
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 4 );
    $the_posts = get_posts( $args );

    foreach( $the_posts as $post ){ ?>

    //The Post Content Goes here...

?>

<div class="pagination">
    <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
</div>
```

**Without plugin you can use like this**

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'cat' => '-10, -72&paged=' . $paged) ); ?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> <?php the_title(); ?></a>
<span><?php the_time('d.m.y') ?></span>
</li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php posts_nav_link(' — ', __('&laquo; Previous Page'), __('Next Page &raquo;')); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but is there anyway without using any plugins?